# DataContext creation in which layer?

Tags: silverlight, frameworks, entity, data-access-layer, datacontext

I am creating a new Silverlight app using RIA.  I am using a Business layer and a data access layer, it looks something like this...

Silverlight->ASP.Net/RIA->C# BLL class library->C# DAL class library
My entity framework model is accessible in all layers.

I'm not sure where to create the DataContext for my Entity Framework requests.  Should I create the context on the RIA (ASP.Net) layer and pass it down to the BLL, then to the DAL, or should I create it in the DAL and pass the LINQ result back up?

If I create it in the DAL and pass an entity back up, lazy loading means that the data is not there yet.  Is it possible that my context will be garbage collected before I get a chance to actually query my data from the database?

Will I run into threading problems if I create the context in my DAL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using RIA servcies anyway, you might as well make use of LinqToEntitiesDomainService<*EfModelGoesHere*> and let RIA services hold a single EF DataContext/model.

We use our own custom POCOs for business logic, but RIA services manages all connections from the client to our various data layers (including direct to EF). Where needed we pass down the single EF model (which is stored in the ObjectContext member of the Domain Context).

It felt right to retain the EF reference, rather than switch to a plain DomainService and has made adding quick (temporary) additions to the Domain Service really easy as we just LINQ direct to the EF model. If we manage it lower down, we then are constantly pulling it back up to the RIA layer to make use of it.

Answer (score 0):

You create the data context in your Silverlight (client) part of the application.  I normally leave my context in a variable in my class so I can reuse it.  It won't get garbage collected until the all references to the class are gone.  Here's a short example loading some objects (entities) from the database asynchronously (with a call back to process the returned objects):

```
public class MyClass

    private _context as MyDomainContext
    private _employees as list(of Employees)

    public sub DoSomething()
        _context = new MyDomainContext
        _context.Load(_context.GetEmployeesQuery(), AddressOf EmployeesLoaded, Nothing)
    end sub

    public sub EmployeesLoaded(loadOp as LoadOperation(Of Employee))
        _employees = new list(of Employee)(loadOp.entities)
    end sub

end class
```

Comment: Scottie meant the Entity Framework *DataContext*, not the *DomainContext*. Nice clean example of the other one though. Cheers